# Postgrey whitelist and log questions

Tags: postfix, whitelist, postgrey

I install Postfix 2.6.6 on Centos 6

1) /etc/postfix/postgrey_whitelist_clients.local is

```
#Clients that should not be greylisted.  See postgrey(8).
senderDomain.digital
```

Restarted postgrey but sometimes the rule is not followed.

> Aug 30 17:03:56 host postgrey[15064]: action=greylist, reason=new, client_name=mail-he1eur01on0113.outbound.protection.outlook.com, client_address=104.47.0.113, sender=ffff@senderDomain.digital, recipient=mmmm@recipientDomain.com
>
> Aug 30 17:03:56 host postfix/smtpd[14291]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from
>   mail-he1eur01on0113.outbound.protection.outlook.com[104.47.0.113]: 450
>   4.2.0 mmmm@recipientDomain.com: Recipient address rejected: Greylisted, see http://postgrey.schweikert.ch/help/recipientDomain.com.html;
>   from=ffff@senderDomain.digital to=mmmm@recipientDomain.com proto=ESMTP helo=EUR01-HE1-obe.outbound.protection.outlook.com

The problem why I need domain senderDomain.digital to be in white list is that outlook.com responds 10 hours after Postgrey requests confirmation instead of 3 or 4 minutes.

2) Another issue is to fully understand postgrey log

*"When a request for delivery of a mail is received by Postfix via SMTP, the triplet CLIENT_IP / SENDER / RECIPIENT is built"*

For all rejected messages Postfix log says "Recipient address rejected", I never find something like "Sender address rejected" in cases that is obvious rejection was because the sender, not the recipient.

I guess it does not make sense to add local addresses to whitelist_recipients unless the user wants all received messages (including bulk spam) be delivered

I am monitoring Postgrey with

```
tail -f /var/log/maillog | grep 'senderDomain.digital'
```

I've just got another rejection from a know couple sender/recipient
Despite whitelisted domain there were previous action=pass for that couple.

3) Can I manually release that message? I guess I cannot because it has been rejected so I have to wait the second message

4) How can I get the info of how long it takes from 450 "try again later" and resend message?

I don't see in the postfix log when message sent the second time is delivered. I also guess it is not possible because the first message has been removed, only the "triplet" has been recorded.

> Sep  2 10:48:29 host postgrey[24084]: **action=greylist**, reason=new,
>   client_name=mail-eopbgr40110.outbound.protection.outlook.com,
>   client_address=40.107.4.110, sender=ffff@senderDomain.digital,
>   recipient=mmmm@recipientDomain.com
>
> Sep  2 11:08:04 host postgrey[24084]: **action=pass**, reason=triplet
>   found, delay=168918,
>   client_name=mail-ve1eur01on0130.outbound.protection.outlook.com,
>   client_address=104.47.1.130, sender=ffff@senderDomain.digital,
>   recipient=mmmm@recipientDomain.com
>
> Sep  2 11:48:36 host postgrey[24084]: **action=greylist**, reason=new,
>   client_name=mail-ve1eur01on0102.outbound.protection.outlook.com,
>   client_address=104.47.1.102, sender=ffff@senderDomain.digital,
>   recipient=mmmm@recipientDomain.com

The only reason of greylisting here (triplet not found) is the IP address.

I've seen today several rejections applied to the same sender.  I guess it is because several 450 loops, each one with a different outlook.com IP Address.

I have a list of outlook.com IP ranges I've added to client_whitelist.local (I don't understand why Postgrey doesn't have it. I didn't have this issue with Google or other known mail servers)

Now I am seeing *action=pass, reason=client whitelist* logs.
They are those retries (I certainly know that because senders are not working at this time).

Anyway I still have some questions I listed earlier like why "senderDomain.digital" is not passed if it is listed in whitelist.local.

Answer (score 2):

> Restarted postgrey but sometimes the rule is not followed.

I didn't see any [reference](http://linux.die.net/man/8/postgrey) saying that postgrey can whitelist sender addresses. It only could whitelist email by:

- Client IP Address
- Recipient Address

That explains why the email is still greylisted after you put **sender address** in the `postgrey_whitelist_clients.local`. It only whitelists clients who have a PTR record *.senderdomain.digital

> For all rejected messages Postfix log says "Recipient address rejected", I never find something like "Sender address rejected" in cases that is obvious rejection was because the sender, not the recipient.

Because you put postgrey checking in `smtpd_recipient_restriction` parameter.

> Can I manually release that message? I guess I cannot because it has been rejected so I have to wait the second message

Rejection means that postfix refuses the message (although in this case the rejection is temporary). How can you release a message which is never accepted by postfix?

> How can I get the info of how long it takes from 450 "try again later" and resend message?

It depends on the sender side. Some sites resent after just 3-5 minutes, others will take one hour. See your log, there some entries about how long one email has been delayed.

```
Sep 2 11:08:04 host postgrey[24084]: action=pass, reason=triplet found, delay=168918
```

Comment: This is incorrect, you can put an email address in the whitelist file. It shows in the documentation that you reference at the start of your post.

Comment: After three years, after server move I faced up the same problem I "fixed".  Anyway  I have to disable Postgrey for this reason: I don't know if other servers like Outlook respond to Postgrey in the same way as it does (every time from a new outlook subdomain) and finally the mail is discarded (and I lose a potencial client). I can add addresses to white list IF I know the recipient.